# How do I change the printed character of a keyboard key in IntelliJ/PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, key, pycharm, keyboard-layout

To make my keyboard more suitable for programming I want to define which character should be assigned to a certain key.

How can I, for example, assign the **'{'** character to another key on my keyboard in IntelliJ/PyCharm?

I intuitively thought that this can be set under **Keymap**, but that's only for shortcuts.

Can it be set within the IDE or do I have to create a custom keyboard layout?

Answer (score 0):

No, this can't be set within the IDE. There are many programs that allow you to remap keyboard shortcuts, but they are OS-specific.